# How to fill shape with gradient stripes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am fairly new to AI and still learning. Like the title stated, i would like to know how to fill the shape with  gradient colors (or so i dont actually know how to call it) such as this[image: example]. I tried with blend tool and it worked but i would like to know if there is any faster way to fill it directly rather than  using  blend tool. Thank in advance !

Comment: Basically, just read the first paragraph of the chosen answer in the duplicate link.

Comment: Ho much faster do you need to be? I mean even with a magic script there is still bookkeeping to inform how to do this. So yeah you can make a 30 -  60 second tasl a 10 second task. But how many times do you exactly need it. See [Is is worth your time](https://xkcd.com/1205/) So clearly if you need this every week you can invest a hour on the task of making it faster. (which you have spent by posting here)

Comment: Thank you Scott and joojaa

Answer (score 0):

## Use the [Gradient tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/gradients.html)

Select the gradient tool and apply color swatches to it. You can choose a gradient pattern and as many color "steps" as you like.

Comment: Thank you but i am confused by gradient pattern. You mean add color manually on gradient bar ? if so it seems slower than using blend tool

Comment: @BongBong Blend = 1 object for *each* blend step. Gradient = 1 object *total*

Comment: i see. Thanks a lot